# How to reimplement material.io components in hyperHTML?

Tags: javascript, material-design, single-page-application, hyperhtml

I am looking at this React example of how material.io component is implemented/integrated with React component:

https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web/blob/master/framework-examples/react/src/Checkbox.js

I wonder how one would go about doing same with hyperHTML since there are no lifecycle event calls within `hyper.Component` like `componentDidMount` or `componentWillUnmount`.

It was said that I can do that after `render` call but that is typically called from outside of component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sorry I've seen this only now.

I'd like to clarify a couple of things:

> there are no lifecycle event calls within hyper.Component like componentDidMount or componentWillUnmount.

If you try latest version, or let's say 1.10+, you will have the ability to define `onconnected(evt) { ... }` and  `ondisconnected(evt) { ... }` methods in each of your `hyper.Component` class definition.

It's a fairly recent feature, unfortunately not documented yet. but it provides all you need to behave like Custom Elements `connectedCallback` and `disconnectedCallback` methods (and remember, there is also an [HyperHTMLElement project](https://github.com/WebReflection/hyperHTML-Element) to create real custom elements).

The following is a basic example:

```
import {Component} from 'hyperhtml';

class Clock extends Component {

  update() {
    this.time = (new Date).toLocaleTimeString();
    this.render();
  }

  // equivalent of Custom Elements connectedCallback
  onconnected() {
    console.log('start time');
    this.update();
    this.timer = setInterval(() => this.update(), 1000);
  }

  // equivalent of Custom Elements disconnectedCallback
  ondisconnected() {
    console.log('end time');
    clearInterval(this.timer);
  }

  render() { return this.html`
    <p
      onconnected=${this}
      ondisconnected=${this}
    >
      ${this.time}
    </p>`;
  }
}
```

I hope this would give you enough power to replicate the material example.

---

The other part I'd like to clarify:

> It was said that I can do that after render call but that is typically called from outside of component.

That's not entirely correct. Yes, the `component.render()` is called automatically, if needed, but what matters is what you return.

I am using the same code I've used for the previous `Clock` example:

```
// same code as before
  render() {
    const p = this.html`
    <p
      onconnected=${this}
      ondisconnected=${this}
    >
      ${this.time}
    </p>`;

    // you have a <p> element here
    // you can do whatever you want
    // example:
    p.addEventListener('click', console.log);

    // now you should return it
    return p;
  }
// rest of the code
```

as you can see, you can always interact with the rendered node. After all, all *hyperHTML* does, is creating the content you write, nothing more, nothing less.

I hope these clarifications would help you to move forward.
Here, eventually, to answer other questions.